# Having a ons-tabbar AND ons-toolbar together

Tags: onsen-ui

I am trying to create a simple app that has a tabbar and tool bar together on a single page, but every time I create a toolbar, it is placed in the front of the content with no formatting. I have the tabbar, that looks like this:

```
<ons-tabbar>
        <ons-tab page="partials/info.html" active="true" icon="fa fa-bar-chart-o" label="Info">
        </ons-tab>
        <ons-tab page="partials/history.html" active="true" icon="fa fa-info-circle" label="History">
        </ons-tab>
        <ons-tab page="partials/contact.html" active="true" icon="fa fa-user" label="Contact">
        </ons-tab>
        <ons-tab page="partials/settings.html" active="true" icon="ion-gear-a" label="Settings">
        </ons-tab>
    </ons-tabbar>
```

The tabbar is completely functional, but when I try to put a ons-tool bar right above it, it bugs out with wrong text formatting and all the content of the partials BEHIND the toolbar:

```
<ons-toolbar fixed-style>
        <div class="left">
            Brand Name
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            Info 1: dsadas
            Info 2: adsadas
        </div>
</ons-toolbar>
```

Is there any way to correct go about doing this? **Alternatively**, I really don't need the full functionality of a tool bar (though it would be nice); all I really need is just a "strip" of `height: 30px and width: 100%` to be statically placed at the top of the app to put some info or numbers. When I use ons-page with my partials, it seems to just be covered up the entire time....

Comment: You mean something like this? http://codepen.io/frankdiox/pen/gpZzGz

Comment: Yes, like that. Is the tabbar and the toolbar really supposed to be nested inside a `ons-page` element? The documentation is not very clear on how to deal with the `ons-page` element...

Comment: `ons-page` should be the root of every page and is necessary for toolbar component: http://onsen.io/reference/ons-page.html